# Make first column bold in CSS

Tags: css

I am aware that most tables have the top row as a table header and that is where users may have a different font, such as putting the data in bold.  For my table, I don't actually need a table header.  I have eight rows with two columns.  I need the first column to be bold and the second not.

I added a css section for td:first-child, but I am obviously missing something else.  The table comes out just fine, but the first column is not bold as I would like it to be.

What am I missing?

```html
    # create email
    $subject = "$Priority - $Ticket - $Specifics"
    $body = @"
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table {
        font-family: calibri;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 500;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    td:first-child {
        font-weight: bold
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:calibri">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Ticket Number</td>
            <td>$Ticket</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Priority Level</td>
            <td>$Priority</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Affected Application</td>
            <td>$AppDown</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Issue Specifics</td>
            <td>$Specifics</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Affected Location</td>
            <td>$Location</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Issue Start Time (EST)</td>
            <td>$StartTime</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number of Affected Users</td>
            <td>$NumUsers</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Critical Event Manager Contacted</td>
            <td>$CEMContact</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    "@
```

This is how the table currently looks:
[image]

Comment: can you please provide image of what you want??

Comment: if you're not going to use a loop and if this table is going to be static then just put `<tr style="font-weight: bold;">` at first row

Comment: Your html code is work...and its display a bold...are try in include head tag twice?

Comment: What's wrong with my suggestion ? You ask for first COLUMN to be bold

Comment: I deleted my answer ...

Comment: Image has been added to show what it looks like.

Comment: And, why the down vote?  It doesn't work, whether or not you say it should.  Otherwise I wouldn't be posting this question.

Comment: Ah must be because of email client - emails have to use pretty basic html and css - think of it as early 2000 and using css2 and html4 in order for it to work.  I would change that first td to a th and then you would have it bold and  it would be more semantically correct

Comment: I though you say rows..haha.. Your code is working fine

Comment: Check this - it's a good guide to what you can use: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

Comment: By the way, if you would have used <th> for the header cells (which is what they should be anyway), they would have been bold by default. And <th>s work in email.

Comment: Thanks all.  I found a rather ugly (in my opinion) way of doing it by just adding `style="font-weight:bold;"` to each <td> in the first column.  I will also review the link Pete provided so I can better understand my options.  Thanks again.

Comment: @sbagnato it's best to inline styles and include those styles in style tags - I use both in all my emails as some clients can't read the style tags and some can't read inline styles!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, in fact it works perfectly on every browser.

The problem maybe is that you are not creating a web page, you are creating a mail message, so you cannot use advanced CSS. Things like ":first-child" will never work in a mail message.

You may use a tool to convert your CSS to email compatible code, here is one: [CSS inliner tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)

Comment: This makes sense.  It works via email for making the table header bold, but I know that is a more simple like of code.  Thank you for this info

Comment: You say, _Things like ":first-child" will never work in a mail message_ but that's not entirely correct. Thunderbird handles this style without problems. Not all email clients do though, so it's best not to rely on advanced features.

Comment: Didn't knew about Thunderbird, thank you, but we still cannot rely on those CSS features for mail messages.